# Nested JSON not parsing correctly in Aws Glue

Tags: json, aws-glue

I have an API response that looks something like below. I am loading it to S3 and I want AWS Glue Crawler to crawl it.  but the Glue Crawler creates one row with many columns. Instead of Rows.  Is this JSON even correct from the API? Should I modify the JSON and put square brackets?

```
{"sammy" : {
    "username"  : "SammyShark",
    "location"  : "Indian Ocean",
    "online"    : true,
    "followers" : 987
  },
  "jesse" : {
    "username"  : "JesseOctopus",
    "location"  : "Pacific Ocean",
    "online"    : false,
    "followers" : 432
  },
  "drew" : {
    "username"  : "DrewSquid",
    "location"  : "Atlantic Ocean",
    "online"    : false,
    "followers" : 321
  },
  "jamie" : {
    "username"  : "JamieMantisShrimp",
    "location"  : "Pacific Ocean",
    "online"    : true,
    "followers" : 654
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, that is not Crawler friendly json. Seems like you need to push the firstname (jamie, drew, etc) into the body with an element name like "firstname". The value for the "firstname" would be the names (jamie, drew, etc)

Comment: Thanks.  I've found this JSON, and most, are AWS Glue friendly.   I was able to manually load it as is into MongoDB.  So next step is to see if I can load it in automated.

Comment: *NOT AWS Glue friendly!